# Weird Behaviour of std::unique

Tags: c++, unique, std

I learning through the std::algorithm, and found out about unique, but upon practicing it my self, I see the output is not what I expected, or should I said not as documentation claim:

> Eliminates all but the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements from the range [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range.

```
vector<int> val = { 5,3,3,3,4};
unique(val.begin(), val.end());
for (auto it = val.begin(); it != val.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it << " ";
```

output: 5 3 4 3 4. isn't it supposed to return: 5 3 4 3 3.

and I thought that it needed to be sort first so I do this:

```
vector<int> val = { 5,3,3,3,4};
sort(val.begin(), val.end());
unique(val.begin(), val.end());
for (auto it = val.begin(); it != val.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it << " ";
```

and the output is: 3 4 5 4 5.

I found out this really odd. does you guys know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cppreference on `std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) answers this for you:

> Relative order of the elements that remain is preserved and the physical size of the container is unchanged. Iterators pointing to an element between the new logical end and the physical end of the range are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values. A call to unique is typically followed by a call to a container's erase method, which erases the unspecified values and reduces the physical size of the container to match its new logical size.

Therefore to truly erase the elements, you should use `vector::erase` also, which the linked page provides an example of:

```
std::vector<int> v { 5, 3, 3, 3, 4 };
auto last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(last, v.end());
for (auto i : v)
    cout << i << "\n";
```

Output is now

> 5
>   3
>   4

Comment: I see, so the only way to use unique is with erase, to remove duplicate value, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that std::unique

```
 "returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range"
```

So to see the new range try:

```
auto new_end = std::unique(val.begin(), val.end());
for (auto it = val.begin(); it != new_end; ++it)
   cout << *it << " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The only guarantees you get from `std::unique` are what you spelled out: the sequence from the beginning iterator to the returned past-the-end iterator is as specified. It is not specified what happens with the spare values in the container starting with the returned past-the-end iterator and continuing until the original sequence end iterator.

There are a few other minor details/guarantees/whatnots that are a part of `std::unique`'s contract, but they are not germane here. The bottom line is that the only thing you can expect from `std::unique` is the sequence from the beginning iterator to the returned new past-the-end iterator, and any remaining values in the original container are not specified.

Your observations are consistent with your implementation's `std::unique` using move semantics, which, for plain `int`s, are equivalent to copy semantics. Hence, the remaining values in the original iterator are copies of what used to be there. This is a typical implementation of `std::unique`, but it is not a requirement.